# how to show an element in a new box when we move it there by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have some columns in my page and i want their objects to be draggable between those columns. this is the script i wrote:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.application').draggable({
                    helper: 'clone'
                });
                $('.dropzone').droppable({
                    drop:function (event,ui) {
                    var id= $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                    var box=$(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                       url: '/application/'+id +'/'+box,
                        type:'GET',
                        data: {"cv_folder_id": box},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $(ui.draggable).remove();
                            $('#'+box).append($(id))
                        }
                        , error: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);


                        }

                    });
                    }
                });

            }
        )
    </script>
```

everything is done good but i cant make the object i remove after dragging it to another column to show up in its new column. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i realize what's your problem.

in javascript:

The remove() method removes the selected elements, including all text and child nodes.

This method also removes data and events of the selected elements.

To remove the elements without removing data and events, use the detach() method instead.

To remove only the content from the selected elements, use the empty() method.

Comment: please give us more detail and information about your problem in your question till we could help you as well as we can.